# Any character $L$ of $L^1(G)$ is given by $L(\phi)=\int_G \phi(x)f(x)dx$ for some bounded function $f$

Tags: measure-theory, locally-compact-groups

The proof of theorem 7, chp. 3, p.60, of Lang's SL2 starts with

> By measure theory, given a character $L\neq0$ of the algebra $L^1(G//K)$, there exists a bounded measurable function $f$ such that $$L(\phi)=\int_F\phi(x)f(x)\,dx, \qquad \forall\phi \in L^1(G//K)$$

$L^1(G//K)$ is the convolution algebra of bi-invariant functions of a locally compact Hausdorff group $G$ wrt to a compact subgroup $K$, but what bi-invariance is is irrelevant here (which is why I only put $L^1(G)$ in the title).

I've studied measure theory before, so I'd probably be fine with a mere more precise reference of the theorems involved, but any more thorough answer will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the definition of the characters $L$? Are they continuous linear maps to $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Instead of linear, we want them be a hom of algebras, so the map should be to $\Bbb C^*$.

Comment: Are you sure? If $L$ is to satisfy $L( \phi) = \int \phi f dx$ for any integrable $\phi$, then the zero function should be sent to $0$.

Comment: I think you are right! Absolutely continuity probably comes from $L$ being, by assumption, not only linear but continuous. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me clarify the definitions. Let $G$ be a locally compact Hausdorff group with Haar measure $\mu$. Then $L^1(G)$ is a commutative Banach algebra when equipped with convolution. For a given subgroup $K$, a function $f$ on $G$ is called **bi-invariant** (with respect to $K$) if $f(k_1 g k_2) = f(g)$ for all $g \in G$ and $k_1,k_2 \in K$. We denote by $L^1(G//K)$ the space of integrable bi-invariant functions. One can verify that it is in fact a subalgebra of $L^1(G)$.

For a Banach algebra $A$ over $\mathbb{C}$, a **character** of $A$ is a morphism of algebras $L: A \to \mathbb{C}$. Explicitely, $L$ is a linear functional which satisfies $L(x y)=L(x) L(y)$ (it is multiplicative). Such a map is always continuous, so it is in fact a morphism of Banach algebras.

---

Now let us prove the claim. Let $L$ be a character of the algebra $L^1(G//K)$. In particular, $L$ is a bounded linear functional on $L^1(G//K)$, which is a subspace of $L^1(G)$. By the Hahn-Banach theorem, $L$ has an extension to a linear functional $L'$ on $L^1(G)$, which has the same norm. Thus $L'$ is in the dual of $L^1(G)$.

For a general $\sigma$-finite measure space $(X,\nu)$, it is well-known that the dual of $L^1(X, \nu)$ is isomorphic to $L^{\infty}(X, \nu)$. Indeed, an isomorphism is given by
$$
f \in L^{\infty}(X, \nu) \longmapsto \left( \phi \mapsto \int_X \phi \, f \; d\nu \right) \in (L^1(X, \nu))^*
$$

**Assuming that the Haar measure on $G$ is $\sigma$-finite**, this result implies that there exists a function $f \in L^{\infty}(G)$ such that
$$
L'(\phi) = \int_G \phi \, f \; d\mu
$$
for all $\phi \in L^1(G)$. By choosing a suitable representative we can always assume that $f$ is bounded. Since $L'$ is equal to $L$ on $L^1(G//K)$, the claim is proved.

---

One difficulty is that the Haar measure on a locally compact Hausdorff group is not necessarily $\sigma$-finite, and the aforementioned map $L^{\infty} \to (L^1)^*$ can fail to be surjective in this case. However, the Haar measure *is* $\sigma$-finite, for example, if $G$ has a countable number of connected components, which is true in many cases.

If $\sigma$-finiteness is not assumed, this can still be fixed by changing slightly the definition of $L^{\infty}$.  A very good reference for this is section 2.3 of Folland's Abstract Harmonic Analysis (2nd ed.). See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/646386/258909) on MSE. With this new definition (which is the same as the standard one when the space is $\sigma$-finite), we always have the isomorphism $L^{\infty} \cong (L^1)^*$ and the rest of the proof carries over.

Comment: Why do you have to be careful when choosing a "suitable representative" to assume that $f$ is bounded? Doesn't $f\in L^\infty(G)$ already mean that it's bounded?

Comment: A general representative of a class $f \in L^{\infty}(G)$ is _essentially_ bounded, i.e. bounded outside some set of measure 0. By adjusting the function on this set of measure 0, we can obtain another representative which is bounded.